# I need to change IDs in a .txt file based on an excel document

Tags: c#, excel, data-analysis

I got a large.txt file where I need to change IDs based on an excel file. The excel table is build like this:

| Old ID | new ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1A1 | 160 |
| 1A10 | 207 |
| 1A11 | 174 |

I have in total 354 IDs to be changed.

The problem is that my algorithm changes 1A10 instead of to 207 to 1600 and 1A11 instead of 174 to 1601.. It just sees 1A1 in the .txt file and directly changes it to 160 and then adds 0 or 1 after that.
Any suggestions how to change that? See code below

```
(...)




ExcelApp.Application excelApp = new ExcelApp.Application();
            DataRow myNewRow;
            DataTable myTable;

            
            //create book,pages and range variables
            ExcelApp.Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"matching.xlsx");
            ExcelApp._Worksheet excelSheet = excelBook.Sheets[1];
            ExcelApp.Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;
            
            //calculate rows and columns
            int rows = excelRange.Rows.Count;
            int cols = excelRange.Columns.Count; 
            
           //define DataTable Name and Column Name
            myTable = new DataTable("TranslationTable");
            myTable.Columns.Add("Plasma", typeof(string));
            myTable.Columns.Add("Thrombus", typeof(string));
            
           //reading columns and rows into DataTable
           for (int i = 2; i < rows; i++)
            {
                myNewRow = myTable.NewRow();
                myNewRow["Plasma"] = excelRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2.ToString();
                myNewRow["Thrombus"] = excelRange.Cells[i, 3].Value2.ToString();
                myTable.Rows.Add(myNewRow); 
                
            }

            //rewrite Plasma file
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\wviegener\Desktop\Stroke\dataExchange\proteinGroups_Plasma.txt");
            String[] row = Regex.Split(sr.ReadToEnd(), "\r\n");
            sr.Close();

            String old_ID;
            String new_ID;


            
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\wviegener\Desktop\Stroke\dataExchange\proteinGroups_Plasma_new.txt");
                for(int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < myTable.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    old_ID = myTable.Rows[j][0].ToString();
                    new_ID = myTable.Rows[j][1].ToString();
                    row[i] = row[i].Replace(old_ID,"Thr" + new_ID);
                    row[i] = row[i].Replace("WDH", "" );
                    

                }
                sw.WriteLine(row[i]);
```

the txt files look like this:

***proteinGroups_Plasma.txt***:

LFQ intensity 1A11_20220429 LFQ intensity 1A12_20220429

***proteinGroups_Plasma_new.txt***:
LFQ intensity Thr1672_20220429  LFQ intensity Thr312_20220429

Comment: what is the code definition of `myTable`, what are some lines from `proteinGroups_Plasma_new.txt`?

Comment: c# is not my forte, but can't you use `Regex.Replace()` instead? Make use of word-boundaries around `old_ID`? I mean, you allready used `Regex.Split()`.

Comment: @JvdV, it looks like the replacement values are being looked up from another file.

Comment: Its worth noting that StreamReader can read line by line which would be better than reading the whole file and splitting it with a regex.

Comment: If `myTable`, key was ordered in reverse natural order , you will do "1A11" before "1A1". and have no problem.

Comment: @Jodrell I have changed my question. Does that help?

Comment: I will also consider that both file are CSv with space séparator so I could map each field to a real object properties and limit the replacement to the part I want. So I know i can't have side effect on some other part of the string

Comment: The initial problem is that `1A10` and `1A11` both contain `1A1` so you have a duplicate key problem. If you do your replacements largest first, you will avoid the initial clash.
Big problems would occur if a Thrombus matched a Plasma.

Comment: Jordel is right: Lenght sould be enough no need to use natural order. 
Sorting by length is a simple `ReplaceTable.OrderByDescending(r => r[0].Length)`.
But you may have still have collision: Given the following translation table "FOO" => "10BAR".
The string "1AFOO" get translated to  "1A10BAR", then to "207BAR".
You may have side effect due to the previous replacement. 
May be search for something to remplace and do only one remplacment by adding a `break;`.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/9E9lJ2

Answer (score 0):

Thats the code now. Works finally

```
   using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using ExcelApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Stroke
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExcelApp.Application excelApp = new ExcelApp.Application();
            DataRow myNewRow;
            DataTable myTable;
            
            
            //create book,pages and range variables
            ExcelApp.Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\wviegener\Desktop\Stroke\dataExchange\matching.xlsx");
            ExcelApp._Worksheet excelSheet = excelBook.Sheets[1];
            ExcelApp.Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;

            //calculate rows and columns
            int rows = excelRange.Rows.Count;
            int cols = excelRange.Columns.Count;

            //define DataTable Name and Column Name
            myTable = new DataTable("TranslationTable");
            myTable.Columns.Add("Plasma", typeof(string));
            myTable.Columns.Add("Thrombus", typeof(string));

            //reading columns and rows into DataTable
            for (int i = 2; i < rows; i++)
            {
                myNewRow = myTable.NewRow();
                myNewRow["Plasma"] = excelRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2.ToString();
                myNewRow["Thrombus"] = excelRange.Cells[i, 3].Value2.ToString();
                myTable.Rows.Add(myNewRow);

            }

            //reverse Datatable 
            DataView dv = myTable.DefaultView;
            dv.Sort = ("Plasma desc");
            DataTable sortedTable = dv.ToTable();
   
            //rewrite Plasma file
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\wviegener\Desktop\Stroke\dataExchange\proteinGroups_Plasma.txt");
            String[] row = Regex.Split(sr.ReadToEnd(), "\r\n");
            sr.Close();
            
            String old_ID;
            String new_ID;
            
            
            //TODO Erstes und letzes Element nicht ausgetasucht
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\wviegener\Desktop\Stroke\dataExchange\proteinGroups_Plasma_new.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < sortedTable.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    old_ID = sortedTable.Rows[j][0].ToString();
                    new_ID = sortedTable.Rows[j][1].ToString();
                    row[i] = row[i].Replace(old_ID, "Thr" + new_ID);
                    row[i] = row[i].Replace("WDH", "");
                    
                    
                }
                sw.WriteLine(row[i]);
                
                
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
        
        
        
                
                
                
                
        }
}
```

Comment: Rather than reverse, I'd try longest first.

Answer (score 0):

If you did something like,

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ReadReplacements()
{
    ExcelApp.Application excelApp = new ExcelApp.Application();

    //create book,pages and range variables
    ExcelApp.Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"matching.xlsx");
    ExcelApp._Worksheet excelSheet = excelBook.Sheets[1];
    ExcelApp.Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;

    //calculate rows and columns
    int rows = excelRange.Rows.Count;
    int cols = excelRange.Columns.Count; 
        
    //reading columns and rows into DataTable
    for (int i = 2; i < rows; i++)
    {
        yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
            excelRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2.ToString(),
            $"Thr{excelRange.Cells[i, 3].Value2.ToString())}";
    }

    yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>("WDH", "");
}

IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>(
        ReadReplacements()
            .OrderBy(pair => pair.Key.Length));
```

and then deleted your datatable, and used `replacements` instead, you could be confident that the order of replacements would not corrupt your data.

This won't address the collision when a Thrombus replacement value contains a subsequent Plasma replacement key. This may not be possible with your business case.

Comment: I am completely new to c#. Can yo maybe tell me the whole "solution?"